# OSGi JAX-RS Connector with Adobe CQ 5.6 (MOXY)

Tags: jax-rs, aem

We are getting an exception while accessing a JAX-RS service installed in my local Adobe CQ (5.6.1). I'm using the OSGi JAX-RS Connector project for JAX-RS integration in CQ using "provider-moxy".

While accessing my test service, the system is is throwing an Exception as follows

```
15.09.2015 18:03:45.862 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1442343820762] GET /services/person/get HTTP/1.1] servletengine Servlet threw exception:  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jaxb/many/MapEntry
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:486)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ServletContainerBridge.service(ServletContainerBridge.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:263)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
at
```

...............................

But the reported class is already present in "org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.0.jar" which is in activated state.

As I'm stuck , any pointers to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

### Update

The stack trace also says

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.many.MapEntry not found by my-bundle [308]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1500)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1923)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.JaxbClassLoader.loadClass(JaxbClassLoader.java:107)
... 91 more
```

But the manifest creation directive for my-bundle is

```
 Import-Package * Import-Package
```

Thanks and Regards,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error can be solved by adding an Import-package statement for "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.many" in my custom bundle.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your own question. Saved me tons of troubles today.